# Memory efficient XML modifications in Spring MVC

Tags: java, xml, spring, xslt, streaming

The method below will return an XML response where some attribute values are pre- & post-fixed.
After trying STAX, I now tried TRAX to transform the XML.
Is there anything that I can do to reduce the memory load?

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

@RestController
public class MyController {

@RequestMapping
public void get(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, TransformerException {

    LOGGER.info("Total {} mb", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000);
    LOGGER.info("Free {} mb", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000);
    LOGGER.info("Used {} mb", (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1000000);

    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new URL("http://remote.domain/big.xml").openStream());
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xsl = new StreamSource(new ClassPathResource("transform.xsl").getInputStream());
    Result result = new StreamResult(response.getOutputStream());
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xsl);
    transformer.setParameter("prefix", "BEFORE");
    transformer.setParameter("postfix", "AFTER");
    response.setContentType("application/xml");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=updated.xml" );
    transformer.transform(xml, result);
    response.flushBuffer();

    LOGGER.info("Total {} mb", Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1000000);
    LOGGER.info("Free {} mb", Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1000000);
    LOGGER.info("Used {} mb", (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()-Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory())/1000000);

}
}
```

Note that the `xsl` normally will be loaded once. For readibility I added everything together in this method.

*EDIT* If I call the method a few times, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. So, I don't think it is *streaming* at all.

Comment: XSLT 1 and 2 use a data model which includes parsing an XML input document into a tree model first to allow arbitrary XPath navigation so I don't understand why you expect there to be any streaming. XSLT 3 published last year introduces a subset of the language for streamed processing, as far as I know in the Java world only Saxon 9.8 EE supports that. So to use streaming with XSLT 3 you both have to rewrite your XSLT code to pass the streamability analysis as well you have to acquire a (trial at least or buy a commercial) license for Saxon 9 EE.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you

Comment: In addition, if you move to Saxon 9 EE and you want to continue to use JAXP you need to make sure you use http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/com/saxonica/config/StreamingTransformerFactory.html as the TransformerFactory.